# How to Get the Index of the First Item Showing in ListView in C#

Tags: c#, listview

Is there any way to get the index of the first item currently showing, when the list is scrollable?

I'm making a CharMap with some extensions and just found that ListView can't contain 64k items (see code below)

```
        for (var i = char.MinValue; i < char.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            var c = Convert.ToChar(i);
            if (!char.IsControl(c))
                lv1.Items.Add(""+c);
        }
```

so decided to load chars when scroll is at some appropriate points (ie first/last 15%) but ListView doesn't give absolute position of the scrollbar.

Comment: Have you tried [ListView.TopItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.topitem(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @Idle_Mind It gives an exception. Seems it's because the View is LargeIcon.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does feel a little hackish, but maybe it will do the job:

```
int getFirstVisibleItem(ListView lv)
{
    ListViewHitTestInfo HI;
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(lv.ClientSize.Width, lv.ClientSize.Height); i += 3)
    {
        HI = lv.HitTest(i, i);
        if (HI.Item != null) return HI.Item.Index;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This does not directly help with your scrolling issue but should find the first visible Item as you have asked. If your Items have extremely weird (ie non-square) shapes you may want to change the travesal code a little..

Comment: Mostly works great but at times returns -1. Could you explain why you chose to increment the for counter (i) by 3?

Comment: To speed up the process a little. You need to have a look at your Items; the counter is used a the pixel coordinate of the tested point and I move it diagonally from the top left corner until I hit the fitdt Item, which should be the first visible item. If the Items are tiny with heavy padding this might missit, though.. you may want to post a screenshot of a case when it misses so we can analyse why it doesn't hit an item. - you can change the increment to 1, but I doubt it would help those cases..

Comment: Thanks! Made a fix not to miss hittest points that are not on the diagonal line y=-x: ht = lv.HitTest(i, i);
    if (ht.Item != null) return ht.Item.Index;
    for (int j = i - incr; j >= 0; j--)
    {
     ht = lv.HitTest(i, j);
     if (ht.Item != null) return ht.Item.Index;
     ht = lv.HitTest(j, i);
     if (ht.Item != null) return ht.Item.Index;

Answer (score -1):

For your requirement implement ListView with custom scrollbar. So you have more control over your scroll position. You decide when to what action based on scroll position. This might be helpful [Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236319/Listview-with-custom-scrollbars)